# exec command not found error in Linux

Tags: bash, shell-script, exec

below commands are giving output and exiting the terminal

```
exec sleep 60
exec pwd
```

below commands throws error. please advise on the exec behaviour

```
$ exec test1.sh
-bash: exec: test1.sh: not found

$ exec cd /home/
-bash: exec: cd: not found
```

Answer (score 3):

- `test1.sh` is most probably not in the path.

  Use this instead if `test1.sh` is in the current directory:

  ```
  exec ./test1.sh
  ```

  Otherwise, specify the complete path or have the command in the `$PATH`.
- `cd` is a shell builtin and there is no external variant of that utility available on your system.

  You can only ask the shell to replace itself with an external command, not with a builtin command. Without knowing *what* was attempted rather than *how* it was attempted, I'm not sure what advice I can say.

  For example, you can do a double exec from an intermediate shell:

  ```
  exec sh -c 'cd /home && exec sleep 60'
  ```

  which will get the `sleep` command running with its current working directory changed to `/home` without leaving any extra shell around.

Comment: exec pwd  is works  but exec cd <dir> is not working
(both are shell builtin "type cd pwd" )

Comment: @VeeraV The issue is that on your system, `cd` is _not available as an external utility_, while `pwd` is.  The `exec` utility is only ever able to start external utilities. The fact that both `pwd` and `cd` are built-in in the shell is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually asked a question, so it's not clear whether the "*exiting the terminal*" is an issue as well as the "*below commands throws error"*.

Other people have explained why trying to run `test1.sh` throws an error, but for completeness I'll reiterate that here. It's because your search path (the `$PATH` variable) intentionally does not include the current directory. To run something that's not in the `$PATH` you have to include at least one directory separator. In the case of something in the current directory the shortest solution is to prefix its name with `./`; so you end up with `./test1.sh`. (You could also use an absolute path, for example `/home/myusername/test1.sh` but that takes more typing.)

**More importantly,** I think, is that you seem to have an expectation that `exec` is required to run an application. **This is not so.** In fact, I would suggest that for now you forget this verb even exists. **Do not ever use `exec`<sup>*</sup>**.

Commands are run simply by using them. So in your first set of examples, you would just write this:

```
sleep 60
pwd
```

And in the second set,

```
./test1.sh

cd /home
```

---

<sup>* At least, never use `exec` until you understand why there is a need for an *occasional* exception from this advice.</sup>